# Separating date from time

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I was trying to find a way to separate the date from the time in part of my code. When I run the code I get the following result:

2021-05-27 00:00:00

However I would like it to just be '2021-05-27'. If anybody can help me with this I'd appreciate it, thanks.

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import os

start=dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
end=date.today()
df=web.DataReader("AAPL",'yahoo',start,end)
newlast_day=df.index[-1]
print(newlast_day)
```

Comment: what problem are you actually trying to solve here? pandas datetime internally always works with date *and* time, no point in separating the two. On the other hand if you just want to *display* datetime in a certain format, you can format to string using `strftime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `newlast_day` is a Timestamp rather than string. It has time zone information (although the time zone values are all zeros). If you just want to get the time string without the time zone part, you can use the [`pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) function to format the display when you get it from a pandas DatetimeIndex object, as follows:

```
newlast_day = df.index[-1].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Result:

```
print(newlast_day)

2021-05-27
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into an array.

```py
splt = newlast_day.split(" ");
```

`splt[0]` will be `2021-05-27`

`splt[1]` will be `00:00:00`